# How to shuffle a list with specific order ? and i also want user input and simple solution

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, python-2.7

Write a program to have a function called triple_shuffle () that takes three lists of the same size and shuffles them concurrently.

Given list like `[10,20,30,40,50]`, `[11,22,33,44,55]`, and `[19,18,17,16,15]`
the first list is shuffled into `[40,50,30,20,10]`, the second `[44,55,33,22,11]` and the third would become `[16,15,17,18,19]`.

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
X = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [10,20,30,40,50]
X, y,  = shuffle(X, y, random_state=6)
print(X)
print(y)
```

output

```
[4,5,3,2,1]
[40,50,30,20,10]
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to shuffle an index list, and then use the list comperhension:

```
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> a, b, c = [10,20,30,40,50], [11,22,33,44,55], [19,18,17,16,15]
>>> lst = list(range(len(a)))
>>> shuffle(lst)
>>> lst
[3, 1, 2, 0, 4]
>>> [a[i] for i in lst]
[40, 20, 30, 10, 50]
>>> [b[i] for i in lst]
[44, 22, 33, 11, 55]
>>> [c[i] for i in lst]
[16, 18, 17, 19, 15]
```

Numpy is also a good choice:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> ar = np.array([a, b, c])
>>> ar
array([[10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
       [11, 22, 33, 44, 55],
       [19, 18, 17, 16, 15]])
>>> ar[:, np.random.permutation(ar.shape[1])]
array([[20, 10, 30, 40, 50],
       [22, 11, 33, 44, 55],
       [18, 19, 17, 16, 15]])
>>> d, e, f = ar[:, np.random.permutation(ar.shape[1])].tolist()
>>> d
[30, 10, 20, 40, 50]
>>> e
[33, 11, 22, 44, 55]
>>> f
[17, 19, 18, 16, 15]
```

Comment: Why not do it like they already did, just with three lists instead of two?

Comment: I mistakenly think that the shuffle of sklearn can only operate on two arrays at the same time. This is indeed a feasible solution. @KellyBundy